# vuejs remove method that removes all items from array that contains a word

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I am trying to remove all items from my array that contains a specific word for example, "_OJ" by using a button. How can i modify my code to do that?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   activeselected:[{"Identifier":"1396",
"name":"LMM_330_OJ_M15_MASTER"
},{"Identifier":"1396",
"name":"LMM_330_OJ_M15_MASTER"
},
{"Identifier":"139s26",
"name":"LMM_320_OK_M15_MASTER"
}]
  },
  methods: {
  removeOk: function(activeselected){
    this.activeselected.splice(index, 1); 
    },
    removeOJ: function(activeselected){
    this.activeselected.splice(index, 1); 
    }
  },
  


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

{{activeselected}}
<br>

<br>
  <button v-on:click="removeOJ(index)">
  Remove Anything with _OJ
  </button>
  
   <button v-on:click="removeOk(index)">
  Remove Anything with _OC
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data have to be function, and you can use filter:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
     activeselected:[{"Identifier":"1396", "name":"LMM_330_OJ_M15_MASTER"}, {"Identifier":"1396", "name":"LMM_330_OJ_M15_MASTER"}, {"Identifier":"139s26", "name":"LMM_320_OK_M15_MASTER"}]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    remove(id){
      this.activeselected = this.activeselected.filter(a => !a.name.includes(id)); 
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{activeselected}}
  <br>
  <br>
  <button v-on:click="remove('_OJ')">
    Remove Anything with _OJ
  </button>
  <button v-on:click="remove('_OK')">
   Remove Anything with _OC
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: what if there is an underscore in front of the name?

Comment: Then just add underscore :)

Answer (score 0):

We need a function that returns a bool that's true when any value of an object contains a substring.  Something like this will do it:

```
const valuesHaveSubstring = (o, s) =>
  Object.values(o).some(value => value.includes(s));
```

Demo:

```js
const valuesHaveSubstring = (o, s) => Object.values(o).some(value => value.includes(s));

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    activeselected: [{
        "Identifier": "1396",
        "name": "LMM_330_OJ_M15_MASTER"
      }, {
        "Identifier": "1396",
        "name": "LMM_330_OJ_M15_MASTER"
      },
      {
        "Identifier": "139s26",
        "name": "LMM_320_OK_M15_MASTER"
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    remove: function(string) {
      this.activeselected = this.activeselected.filter(o => !valuesHaveSubstring(o, string))
    },
  },

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  {{activeselected}}
  <br>

  <br>
  <button v-on:click="remove('_OJ')">
  Remove Anything with _OJ
  </button>

  <button v-on:click="remove('_OxxxC')">
  Remove Anything with _OC
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Vzupo - fyi, had the filter condition inverted. Fixed.

Comment: ok will try this one